# Remove Repeated Pages in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using List component iReport the data is populating but the pdf has two pages. The data in 2nd page is same as first page. I have 25 records in db and I want to populate in one page. The table data keep repeating in pdf pages. Is there any setting in list to avoid it? I will appreciate for your great help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset1">
        <parameter name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from CALENDAR WHERE REGION=$P{ID} ]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="REGION" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="YEAR" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="HOLIDAY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DATE_PICKER" class="java.sql.Date"/>
        <field name="APPLICABLE_FROM" class="java.sql.Date"/>
        <field name="APPLICABLE_TO" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from USERS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="EMP_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="LEVEL_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="REG_DIV_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PROFILE_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="FINANCE_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="NOMINEE_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PASSPORT_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PERSONAL_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="SALARY_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STATUS" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="CREATE_DATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="87">
            <image>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="52" y="38" width="123" height="47"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/user/Desktop/image003.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="453" y="30" width="62" height="55"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/user/Desktop/image002.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="89" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="52" y="53" width="464" height="29"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                        <datasetParameter name="ID">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="29" width="464">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="28" y="5" width="197" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{HOLIDAY_NAME}+"  "]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <line>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="27" width="464" height="1"/>
                        </line>
                        <line>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="1" height="28"/>
                        </line>
                        <line>
                            <reportElement x="463" y="0" width="1" height="28"/>
                        </line>
                        <line>
                            <reportElement x="225" y="0" width="1" height="28"/>
                        </line>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="301" y="6" width="100" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{DATE_PICKER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="52" y="30" width="464" height="23" backcolor="#DD6626"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="35" width="181" height="23"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["HOLIDAYS LIST"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="353" y="35" width="124" height="23"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["DATE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Are you using SQL datasource? Can you post the snippet of jrxml file?

Comment: Yes i am using SQL datassource.The pdf contains repeated pages which should not happen.Table may contain duplicate value. The list prints all the data in db including repeated values which is ok but after that it again prints from beginning i.e whole data again repeats which leads to duplicate pages in pdf.

Comment: If the table `USERS` contains duplicate rows you can use `DISTINCT` in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your report is designed so the List repeats for every user. If that's not what you want then you need to either change the main query `select * from USERS` to something that returns only a single row, or you need to move the List into a band that does not repeat (like the Title or the Summary band).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRQLErOgiNA&context=C34dac3cADOEgsToPDskI7lC_sotZz31ifSF5Q9zxt

Hope this link helps. Also try isRepeatedValue property as false.

Comment: yes I tried, it is for duplicate values in resultset which suppress for   isRepeatedValue property as false.But i want page should not repeat.